# Compiling cpp helper function with main.cu using NVCC compiler

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, cuda, fatal-error, nvcc

I'm having an issue on creating a Makefile to compile my main file as a .cu file and my helper function as a cpp file. The reason I'm using cpp is that the helper function "sequence.cpp" is just a class that I use in my main.cu.

Update: I edited the makefile. Working on Windows 10 with VS code.

```
#compilers
CC = gcc
NVCC = nvcc 
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -O3
NVCCFLAGS = -std=c++17 -O3
SOURCES = main.cu 

#directories
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH = /usr/local/cuda
CUDA_LIB = -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64 -lcudart

#source files
CPP_FILES = helper_functions.cpp sequence.cpp
CUDA_FILES = main.cu

#object files
OBJ_FILES = $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)
CUDA_OBJ_FILES = $(CUDA_FILES:.cu=.o)

#Targets
all: executable

executable: $(OBJ_FILES) $(CUDA_OBJ_FILES)
$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) $(CUDA_OBJ_FILES) -o executable $(CUDA_LIB)


%.o: %.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.cu
$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@



clean:
rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(CUDA_OBJ_FILES) executable
```

This is the following output when I run make.

```
gcc -std=c++17 -O3 -c helper_functions.cpp -o helper_functions.o
gcc -std=c++17 -O3 -c sequence.cpp -o sequence.o
nvcc  -std=c++17 -O3 -c main.cu -o main.o
main.cu
tmpxft_000080e8_00000000-10_main.cudafe1.cpp
nvcc  -std=c++17 -O3 helper_functions.o sequence.o main.o -o executable -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
helper_functions.o
sequence.o
main.o    
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'helper_functions.o', object file assumed   
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'sequence.o', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'main.o', object file assumed
helper_functions.o : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
make: *** [Makefile:25: executable] Error 2
```

I initially thought to remove the "-o main.o" and "-o sequence.o". From what I found online, is that the c1 compiler is getting picked over NVCC and not sure how to say to use NVCC when I thought my "CXX = nvcc" does that.Another thing I tried was using another compiler command "CPP = gcc" for my sequence file.  I thought this was the most straight forward way to do this. Should I just make my helper function a cu file? Thanks!

(update) I am now seeing the error message 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'. Is this error message also related to the unrecognized source files main.o and sequence.o? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't just show the errors.  Please also show the compile command that was printed before the error messages were printed.  Without that we can't be sure why you are seeing this error.

Comment: My apologizes, I just updated my post to include the messages before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is reporting that one of the .o files is 32-bit (described as x86 for historical reasons) and the other is 64-bit (x64).

From the make output, it looks like sequence.cpp was not recompiled, so presumably it had earlier been compiled using a different architecture. Try deleting both .o files and running make again.

Comment: Or run `make clean` then re-run `make`.

Comment: From what was hidden in the question, it is likely that the stale object files were compiled with 32 bit gcc, thus the unrecognized format warning as well

Comment: hi @talonmies, I tried deleting the the object files and re run make but led to the same issue. Is there a 64 bit gcc? From what I read online it saying that c1 is a compiler from MS compiler and its being selected. Is there a way to edit which compiler I want to use? Thank you!

Comment: My point wasn’t 64 versus 32 bit compiler but trying to mix gcc and MSVC. If you are working on Windows with CUDA you *must* use  MSVC